Write the polynomial $(2X_1^2-X_1X_2+2X_2^2)(2X_2^2-X_2X_3+2X_3^2)(2X_3^2-X_3X_1+2X_1^2)$ as a polynomial of fundamental symmetric polynomials
Write the polynomial  $F(X_1,X_2,X_3)=(2X_1^2-X_1X_2+2X_2^2)(2X_2^2-X_2X_3+2X_3^2)(2X_3^2-X_3X_1+2X_1^2)\in \mathbb{Z}[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ as a polynomial of fundamental symmetric polynomials, i. e. Find a polynomial G$ \in \mathbb{Z}[X_1,X_2,X_3]$ such that $G(S_1,S_2,S_3)=F(X_1,X_2,X_3)$, where $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$ are the fundamental symmetric polynomials, i.e. $S_1=X_1+X_2+X_3$,
$S_2=X_1X_2+X_2X_3+X_3X_1$ ,$S_3=X_1X_2X_3$.
I know that this is a technical problem and I would appreciate if someone could provide an algorithm for solving any problem of the type: If $F(X_1,X_2,X_3)=P(X_1,X_2)P(X_2,X_3)P(X_3,X_2)$, then write F as a polynom of fundamental symmetric polynomials, where $P \in \mathbb{Z}[X_1,X_2]$.
My attempt:
I know how to write basic polynomials as polynomials of fundamental symmetric polynomials, but this aproach seems that it would take an unreasonable amount of time.
For example:
If $F(X_1,X_2,X_3)=X_1^3+X_2^3+X_3^3+2X_1X_2+2X_2X_3+2X_3X_1$, I know how to write this in the way described above because this is a simple polynomial.
